# How to check incoming file transfer status in apache commons io monitor

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

I have implemented a simple file listener using [Apache commons io monitor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html).I have also implemented a selenium script that simply do is download file into the pre hard coded path folder.That is totally working fine.My listener monitoring downloaded files and collect the necessary information.According to my requirement i should be able to stop the file listener once my selenium script is finished execution.To do that i must know that the incoming **file transferring status** to handle it better way.because i can not stop listener middle of the file transferring.(sometimes download file can be heavy so it will take some time to download).So how can i know that incoming file status in Apache commons io monitor before stop the file listener.If any one knows please let me know.

**Sample code snippet**

```
    public class SimpleTestMonitor {
    // A hardcoded path to a folder you are monitoring .
    public static final String FOLDER =
            "/home/skywalker/Desktop/simple-test-monitor/watchdir";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The monitor will perform polling on the folder every 5 seconds
        final long pollingInterval = 5 * 1000;

        File folder = new File(FOLDER);

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            // Test to see if monitored folder exists
            throw new RuntimeException("Directory not found: " + FOLDER);
        }

        FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(folder);
        FileAlterationMonitor monitor =
                new FileAlterationMonitor(pollingInterval);
        FileAlterationListener listener = new FileAlterationListenerAdaptor() {
            // Is triggered when a file is created in the monitored folder
            @Override
            public void onFileCreate(File file) {
                try {
                    // "file" is the reference to the newly created file
                    System.out.println("File created: "
                            + file.getCanonicalPath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }

            // Is triggered when a file is deleted from the monitored folder
            @Override
            public void onFileDelete(File file) {
                try {
                    // "file" is the reference to the removed file
                    System.out.println("File removed: "
                            + file.getCanonicalPath());
                    // "file" does not exists anymore in the location
                    System.out.println("File still exists in location: "
                            + file.exists());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        };

        observer.addListener(listener);
        monitor.addObserver(observer);
        monitor.start();
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://andreinc.net/2012/06/30/writing-a-simple-file-monitor-in-java-using-commons-io/)

Comment: this is good question - i have similar problem, when file is copied is over network then there are two things triggered: onFileCreate() which will fail in my code as file is not yet done copying, then after file is copied then onFileChange() is triggered. this is bad designed, as onFileCreate() should only tigger when complete file is done.